# How can I find artisanal bakeries in Madrid?

Tags: localisation, degrowth

For me, artisanal refers to local production with traditional methods that, due to its local focus and valorisation of time taken for production, are less resource intensive than industrial mass production.

Thereby "bakeries" is just one example of a seeked alternative and more sustainable form of consumption and "Madrid" just one example to indicate the search within an urban context.

What are techniques for one to identify these types of productions are than walking around to physically encounter them?

Comment: I think this questions belongs on Travel.SE, if you're really interested in finding a bakery in Madrid. If this is just a "sample" question, then I think it is too broad. Either way, I can't see how it can fit on this site.

Comment: I agree with @Earthliŋ when saying that of this is a sample question is too broad. But if you are interested in sustainable shops, bakeries, ... in Madrid I can write an answer with some useful resources.

Comment: Very appreciated @A.A! What do you think, where is the potentially best place online to collect such information about sustainable alternatives?